# Statistical test on patients data repeating over 9 weeks for 6 patients for 15 variables all variables and some information cannot be disclosed

Tags: hypothesis-testing

There is a situation I am dealing with here I have a data

| ANO | WK | GRP | lgSc | TS | THS | GS | GHS | US |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 419 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 199 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| 263 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 4 |
| 263 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 4 |
| 263 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 |

As you see in data I have 6 patient in control and 6 patient in treatment.
For group 2 I already segregated the data `group2=sorted1[sorted1['GRP']==2]` and
`group1=sorted1[sorted1['GRP']==1]`.

The problem is I want to find correlation between (*THS* a categorical variable vs *GS* another categorical variable also *GS* categorical vs *US* continuous variable) but the problem lies more with the weekly repetition of data for- ANO 263 the readings of data are taken for 9 weeks.

I cant determine whether I should directly find correlation ignoring this same patient repeated over weeks or I should go For repeated measure ANOVA or is there a better statistical model available.

The two variable are RBC count vs Hygiene, RBC is continuous while Hygiene is from 0-3 0 being best. Data is collected on weekly basis and 6 patient study repeated over weeks

The second study is the correlation of *smoking habit* being labeled from 0 being no smoking to 4 being high smoking (defined as everyday smoking) with
energy level of doing activity labeled as 0 for no activity and 5 as daily activity while 3 being alternate activity.

I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Statistical test on patients data repeating over weeks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534953/statistical-test-on-patients-data-repeating-over-weeks)

Comment: Please not reask a question, you should edit your original question. When edited it will enter a review queue for possible reopening. But I believe your post needs substantial editing, now it lacks sufficient detail to be answerable.

Comment: No problem its just really hard to understand this platform I will try uploading another question but I will have to see how much info I can use without revealing anything confidential. Thanks for the help